# Why can't I put namespace in parent class constructor call?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, namespaces

So I know that I am doing something very wrong according to purists, which is inheriting from std::vector, but I wanted to add very specific functionality which I think has a lot of sense as a child of vector.
Anyway, this is not my main concern.

I have my class :

```
class A : public std::vector<std::vector<double>>
{
public:
    A(size_type n, const value_type& val);
    ... other moethods ...
};
```

What I don't understand is, in the constructor, why does :

```
Matrix::Matrix(size_type n, const value_type& val):
    vector(n, val)
{
}
```

work, while if I put :

```
Matrix::Matrix(size_type n, const value_type& val):
    std::vector(n, val)
{
}
```

it won't compile ? (Using GCC-4.8) I don't have *using namespace std* declarations anywhere in my code.

Comment: It expects the name of the constructor, not type.

Comment: Post an self-contained code sample that reproduces the error.

Comment: You shouldn't really be deriving from std::vector. Make it as a member instead.

Comment: If you must inherit from std::vector, might I recommend private inheritance rather than public?

Comment: But I use the standard operations (push_back, etc...) of vector elsewhere in my code (note: this is just for prototyping, it's not production code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I put namespace in parent class constructor call?

You can, and you should. But you need to specify the template parameters of the base class:

```
Matrix::Matrix(size_type n, const value_type& val): std::vector<std::vector<double>>(n, val)
//                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should not publicly derive from `std::vector`, but you already know that.

Comment: Okay, very dumb of me. Thank you !